# solidity: call contract function from another contract with the same msg.sender

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I have a function that needs to call the transfer method on another contract.
I want the transfer method to be called from the address of the original caller and not the contract.
Is it possible?

This is the code:

```
function buyGameBundle(string calldata id) external nonReentrant {
    structGameBundles  memory currentItem = _gameBundles[id];
    require(currentItem.exists == true, "bundle does not exists");
    require(currentItem.totalSupply > 0, "there are no more bundles left");
    if (currentItem.cost > 0) {
        erc20.transfer(_feesAccount, currentItem.cost);
    }
    currentItem.totalSupply = currentItem.totalSupply.sub(1);
    _gameBundles[id] = currentItem;
    emit BuyGameBundle(_msgSender(), id, currentItem.cost);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work with `msg.sender`, but it would work if the target contract uses `tx.origin`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
erc20.transfer(_feesAccount, currentItem.cost);
```

Your current code performs a **message call** ([docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.6/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html#message-calls)). Another name for the same thing is an **EVM call**. It uses storage of the **target** contract, and the `msg.sender` is your contract (not the original transaction sender).

If you want the `msg.sender` to be the original transaction sender (the user), you need to use a delegatecall ([docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.6/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html#delegatecall-callcode-and-libraries)). But... a delegatecall uses storage of the caller (your contract; not the called contract), so it's mostly useful for proxy contracts.

---

For security reasons, it's not possible to execute a function in a target contract, using the target contract storage and `msg.sender` of the original sender.

If it were possible, you could theoretically steal tokens from anyone who doesn't/can't verify your contract source code. Example:

```
usdt.transfer(attacker, usdt.balanceOf(victim));
weth.transfer(attacker, weth.balanceOf(victim));
// ...
```

Comment: Apparently there are some scenarious that it is possible to call another contracts function as that contract .. I was curious and have been able to replicate the scenario described here (on the testnet of course): https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/131168/just-got-my-contract-drained-how , but I am still confused about this

Answer (score 3):

Needing to transfer funds from someone is such a common pattern that it is built right into the ERC20 specification, and is used in almost every DeFi contract ever.

What you need to use is `transferFrom()` rather than `transfer()`. It takes a "from" address as the first parameter, and if the sending user has approved your contract to move their funds, then the call will succeed.

In your case the transfer line would change to:

```js
erc20.transferFrom(msg.sender, _feesAccount, currentItem.cost);
```

The sender will need to approve your contract first.

Here are the ERC20 specifications.
https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ERC20s and want to transfer another account's tokens from within a seperate contract, the correct method to use is `transferFrom`. This requires an `allowance` to be given to the contract in which `transferFrom` is being called. This is done using `approve` or `increaseAllowance` (the latter is recommended).

In general, however, if you wish to call another contract's method in the context of the current contract, i.e. with the same `msg.sender` (amongst other things), you can use `delegatecall`. See https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/types.html#address for more details.